# understanding python class variable

Tags: python, class, variables, instance

Why do we have template_name = None as class variable here?(from django source code)

It's because if self.template_name is None, would raise an error?
(self.template_name would look for instance variable and if it's not there, would return the class variable)
If so, wouldn't it be better to have `def __init__(self): self.template_name = None ?`

```
class TemplateResponseMixin(object):
    """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    A mixin that can be used to render a template.                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    """
    template_name = None
    response_class = TemplateResponse

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        Returns a response with a template rendered with the given context.                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        """
        return self.response_class(
            request = self.request,
            template = self.get_template_names(),
            context = context,
            **response_kwargs
        )

    def get_template_names(self):
        """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        Returns a list of template names to be used for the request. Must return                                                                                                                                                                                              
        a list. May not be called if render_to_response is overridden.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        """
        if self.template_name is None:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of "
                "'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'")
        else:
            return [self.template_name]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TemplateResponseMixin is a mixin which is not using an init, to make it easier to use in a mutiple inheritence. It does not need its own state, so it does not need a constructor. This also makes the inheritence easier because you don' t need to call a constructor on it in your subclass.

The template_name is set as a class instance obviously because there is no constructor. It implies that it should be set from the subclass. Also, changing the value of it will affect all future instances of that mixin.

Comment: Thank you. Question for mixin. Another name for Mixin would be `function composition`?

Comment: @Eugene No, function composition is an entirely unrelated concept (it's an operation on functions, whereas Mixins are a kind of class).

Comment: Oh I just made up the word, didn't know if there was a term `function composition`.. I meant `mixing is to combine functions in another class`. (opposed to combine functions/datas in another class, which would be `inheritance`)

Comment: Mixin is a type of class that does not have its own state and merely "mixes in" more funtionality, usually to make it qualify as a certain interface. Composition would be where you make a class that has member instances of other classes which it uses to delegate to.